# I cannot login to skype on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, skype

I recently installed skype 4.3, my distro is ubuntu 14.04!
When I click to login skype seems to trying to login but ater 2 seconds fails and the login screen is coming again.
Can someone help me with straightforward instructions what is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: list the output of the command `skype`

Comment: I had the same problem with skype 4.2, but installing 4.3 resolves the problem. The last version is 4.3.0.37-1. Maybe you should update it. I have no problem in Ubuntu 14.04. Some reported [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Can-t-sign-in-Ubuntu-12-04/td-p/838226) the following:  1. delete <home_dir>/.Skype 2. restart skype and login.

Answer (score 2):

Try to reinstall skype by using these [instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/skype-4-3-install-in-ubuntu-1404/). I recommend you this because i also installed skype on my computer using this method, and it's working fine on mine **Ubuntu 14.04**.

Comment: Thanks man, I don't know exactly what was the problem, but now it works!

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on ubuntu 14.04, Open terminal CTRL+ALT+T Type "Sudo apt-get install skype" it may update some files good luck

Answer (score 0):

1. Login into Skype.
2. When it fails quit Skype.
3. Then login into Skype in browser.
4. Then log out.
5. Login into Skype software program again